# camera crashes if called by intent

Tags: android, android-intent, camera

My personalized camera crashes if called by Intent but if the apps launch directly to camera, it works. My problem is, if the camera is not set as launcher and if called via intent the camera was showed but it will crash if the capture button was pressed.

I have two class, 1st is the `startup screen` and the 2nd class is the `camera`. The startup screen is the launcher and the camera class is the default on the manifest declaration. If I run the apps, the startp screen show and if the user click the button "Start Camera" it will call the camera class via intent, now if I tap/click the capture button, the camera crash and stop.

This is my intent code to call the camera class;

```
public void startCamera(View paramView)
 {
   Intent stCam = new Intent(GPSInitialize.this, MainActivity.class);
   stCam.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK); 
   stCam.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);
   startActivity(stCam);
   locationManager.removeUpdates((LocationListener) GPSInitialize.this);
   finish();
 }
```

The logcat:

```
05-12 00:17:25.368: E/AndroidRuntime(1563): java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
05-12 00:17:25.368: E/AndroidRuntime(1563):     at android.graphics.Bitmap.nativeCopy(Native Method)
05-12 00:17:25.368: E/AndroidRuntime(1563):     at android.graphics.Bitmap.copy(Bitmap.java:555)
05-12 00:17:25.368: E/AndroidRuntime(1563):     at com.joules.camera3100.MainActivity$3.onPictureTaken(MainActivity.java:443)
05-12 00:17:25.368: E/AndroidRuntime(1563):     at android.hardware.Camera$EventHandler.handleMessage(Camera.java:917)
05-12 00:17:25.368: E/AndroidRuntime(1563):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
05-12 00:17:25.368: E/AndroidRuntime(1563):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
05-12 00:17:25.368: E/AndroidRuntime(1563):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
05-12 00:17:25.368: E/AndroidRuntime(1563):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-12 00:17:25.368: E/AndroidRuntime(1563):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
05-12 00:17:25.368: E/AndroidRuntime(1563):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
05-12 00:17:25.368: E/AndroidRuntime(1563):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
05-12 00:17:25.368: E/AndroidRuntime(1563):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Why you are calling "finish();" after "startActivity(stCam);" ?? finish() will close the activity.

Comment: i use finish to end the first activity or the startup class. That is why i put finish(); actually i would really close the startup class before calling another class, in this view, minimal memory will use if previewing the camera. Is this method is wrong?

Comment: Share codes of your camera class and logcat also.

Comment: You did memory copy in onPictureTaken(), which caused the OutOfMemoryError. Be careful of the data size.

Answer (score 0):

Hello your problem is not in camera but Memory issue. please check your internal memory when capture Image because there are no memory for store new image. first check memory availability and then capture image.

Comment: how to check the memory?I'd check the storage memory and show available space is 9.83gb. I think this is large enough for the image.

Comment: go to settings->storage and check internal memory or just remove unused images from gallary or apps from device.

Comment: have you check your internal memory or sdcard size? because your images are stored in internal memory.

Comment: yes, my internal free memory is 9.83gb and the external memory available space is 12.65gb.

Comment: If i change the manifest launcher directly to the camera, the apps works but if I change the launcher to my startup class, then call the camera from the button of the startup class, the camera show but it will crash if I start capturing the image.

Comment: Is there anyway to completely close the class and open another class?

Comment: write ActivityName.finish() before intent call.